# I got an error when I try to deploy a project in React to GitHub Page

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-actions, github-pages

There's a lot of steps that `GitHub` executes its workflow.

Running `Build web-app` returns the following errors:

```
Error [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-is" from "/home/runner/work/financare/financare/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
```

```
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-is" from "/home/runner/work/financare/financare/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
    at onRollupWarning (file:///home/runner/work/financare/financare/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:46368:19)
    at onwarn (file:///home/runner/work/financare/financare/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:46138:13)
    at Object.onwarn (file:///home/runner/work/financare/financare/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25149:13)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///home/runner/work/financare/financare/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23784:26)
    at file:///home/runner/work/financare/financare/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23744:26
```

The workflow for the `build` is:

```yaml
name: deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
      - name: Build web-app
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
      - name: Deploy to gh-pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./build
```

I wish I could deploy my project on GitHub, could anyone please advise?

Comment: react-is is a peerDependency of styled-components, which means it needs to be explicitly installed separately if you're on npm < 7